# ReflectionException - Middleware class does not exist Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5, middleware

I am building an API with stateless HTTP basic authentication in Laravel 5.2, as per documentation [Stateless HTTP Basic Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication#stateless-http-basic-authentication) , I have created following Middleware

app/Http/Middleware/AuthenticateOnceWithBasicAuth.php

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Auth\Middleware;

use Auth;
use Closure;

class AuthenticateOnceWithBasicAuth
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return Auth::onceBasic() ?: $next($request);

    }

}
```

And then registered it in Kernel.php

app/Http/kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'auth.basic.once' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateOnceWithBasicAuth::class,
];
```

I am using it in route as follows

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth.basic.once'], function () {

Route::get('service/create', function ()    {
    return response()->json(['name' => 'Abigail', 'state' => 'CA'], 200);
});

});
```

But it is giving me

ReflectionException in Container.php line 734:
Class App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateOnceWithBasicAuth does not exist

[image]

I have run following commands but with no success

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan optimize
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In terminal, run "composer dump-auto" and "php artisan clear-compiled". That should fix it.

Comment: @IllegalPigeon Have already tried it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well first of all look at the namespaces:

```
namespace Illuminate\Auth\Middleware;
```

you should rename it to:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
```

in the middleware you need to do something like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
   if (!Auth::onceBasic()) {
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: In that case it creates a cookie laravel_session and XSRF-TOKEN. Which is same as using basic auth.

Comment: not sure what you whant to get but i think maybe: return `Auth::onceBasic() ? $request : $next($request);` try with the `$request` return on succes.

Comment: I want to implement HTTP Basic Authentication without setting a user identifier cookie in the session